# How to delete a table row having <input> with property data-assigned-id="183" in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to delete the specific row(each  is generated through foreach)having  in jQuery.Below code is my table tr structure.

```
<tr class="eachitem">
    <td>
        <img src="/Content/images/pro2.jpg" style="width:200px;height:auto">
        <p>pro2.jpg</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="preview" name="preview" type="checkbox" value="true">
        <input name="preview" type="hidden" value="false">
    </td>
    <td class="qtyid">
        <input class="qty" type="text" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>
        <input id="deleteCart" type="submit" value="Delete" data-assigned-id="183">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input id="updateCart" type="submit" value="Update" data-assigned-id="183">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Better have a generic title and add the details in the body of question. Just a glance at the title shows its very very specific to you, and not useful for others. Try to make questions as generic as possible, there was in fact a close reason for such question in the past

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attribute selector `[]` for getting the input with `data-assigned-id='183'`

```
 $("input[data-assigned-id='183']").closest("tr").remove();
```

After getting the particular input element, then use `.closest("tr")` to get the parent row of that element.

Then use `.remove()` to delete the element.

Answer (score 0):

find that id and remove parent tr as following should work

```
   $("input").each(function(){
         if($(this).data('assigned-id') ==183){
             $(this).closest('tr.eachitem').remove()
          }
    })
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ac2d8b5/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your `ID` attribute from `delete` and `update` buttons as they as generated in loop (so will be duplicate IDs there). You can assign a class name to them like(for delete button) :

```
 <input  type="submit" class="deleteCart" value="Delete" data-assigned-id="184">
```

And then based on which **delete** button is clicked , you can find corresponding closest `<tr>` element and `remove` that:

**Jquery Code** will be like below:

```
 $(".deleteCart").click(function(){  
   $(this).closest('tr').remove()
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xbcf0Luh/)